# Elementor video opacity

Tags: wordpress, video, opacity, elementor

For all of you that used **Elementor** as **Wordpress** plugin, are you able to adjust `video background` opacity? I know that `picture background` is able to do that, but not goes to video.

I was trying to put *Title* and some short *Paragraph* description on my video, if I was able to lower my video opacity.

Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set opacity of background video in Background Overlay option. You can check in below image.

[image]

Comment: Great it worked, turn out this is the way to do it. :D
(I thought I have to do it as the same way as changing an image opacity)